Fill row with fixed max-width elements
When there is free space in the container, the browser increases the width of the elements to fill it.
I need the opposite behavior, so that the browser shrinks the width of the elements enough to make room for the next element.
I know how to do this with JS, but I would like a pure CSS solution.
I've dropped the JS code below so you can see what I mean.


function resizeLayout() {
  var item_max_size = 200;

  var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
  var container_width = container.getBoundingClientRect()['width'];

  var items_need = Math.ceil(container_width / item_max_size);
  var new_width = container_width / items_need + 'px';
  var items = container.getElementsByClassName('item');

  for (const node of items) {
    node.style.width = new_width;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  resizeLayout();
});

window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  resizeLayout();
});
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: yellow;
}

.item {
  background: green;
  border: 2px black dashed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>




The number of elements is not predetermined, there can be any number of them.
So, it is impossible to calculate what percentage each block should take up so that they fit in one row. Plus, this implementation will simply result in all the blocks being placed in one row.
We want them to wrap to the next row when filled.

You need to add flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 12 - 10px); to item that's it. If you add more elements or number of box is not fixed still it will work. Currently I have used 12 box then move to next row, you can change that as per your need.
This is code for same link


html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: yellow;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 12 - 10px);
  background: green;
  border: 2px black dashed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  
</div>




We need them to wrap into a new row, not just be placed one after the other in one line.

You just divided the container width by 12, thereby fixing the number of elements per line, and then removed 10px from each block. This makes no sense. In this case, the blocks need to be either 200px or less, and there should be no empty spaces in the block. If the user changes the window size, the blocks should react accordingly. See how it works in my example, try changing the window size and see how it reacts.

You can use media query for that. Little bit of understanding will be required from your side too.
